# How to set parent process' shell env from child process

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, inter-process-communicat

The child process has a value which must be passed onto the parent process. I am using python's `subprocess.Popen` to do that, but child process's `TEMP_VAR` is not visible from the parent's shell?

```
import subprocess
import sys

temp = """variable_val"""
subprocess.Popen('export TEMP_VAR=' + temp + '&& echo $TEMP_VAR', shell=True)
//prints variable_val
subprocess.Popen('echo $TEMP_VAR', shell=True)
//prints empty string
```

Is there a way to do this interprocess communication without using `queues` (or) Popen's - `stdout/stdin` keyword args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are copied from parent to child, they are not shared or copied in the other direction. All `export` does is make an environment variable in the child, so its children will see it.

Simplest way is to `echo` in the child process (I'm assuming it is a shell script) and capture it in python using a pipe.

Python:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'gash.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = proc.communicate()[0]

print "output:", output
```

Bash (gash.sh):

```
TEMP_VAR='yellow world'
echo -n "$TEMP_VAR"
```

Output:

```
output: yellow world
```